# Sikuli - NameError: global name 'openApp' is not defined

Tags: automated-tests, nameerror, sikuli

I'm calling a sikuli function, inside Sikuli IDE, but I get this error "NameError: global name 'openApp' is not defined"...

If I try to do openApp('calc') in a new Sikuli blank file, it works, but if I use in another .sikuli file like:

```
def sample():
    import myLib
    # my Lib is .py file that I've created and put it on sikuli-script.jar
    var = somevalue
    myLib.myFunction(something)
    openApp('calc')
```

I get the error with "openApp" and other sikuli funcions like "Key" (ex: Key.ENTER) too...

Hope I had explained that well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Sikuli will insert a `from sikuli import *` into all main files. This error tends to occur when you import sikuli modules. If you are importing modules, you will need to add the import manually. See the [documentation](http://doc.sikuli.org/globals.html#importingsikuliscripts) for more advice.

Answer (score 1):

If your tests are in the same folder basically you can do,

```
import testName
reload(testName)
from testName import *
```

This will import your test and execute it's content.

*testName should be name of the file without .sikuli extension*

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem was solved by putting ***from sikuli import **** at the first line of any file you are importing.  I hope this helps!
 
I only mentioned this, because with the imported files, I had the greatest overall success with this one, and it became habit to make this the first line.